# how to recognize certain character and save strings after it

Tags: python, string

I want to write codes used for catching data from file_1 to file_2.

here is part of file_1

```
RESISTANCE NUMBERS
   2  0     1.000     1.000     1.000    1.000    1.000
PROFILE        30
     0.000    47.010     1.000     <#1>     0     0.000     0
     4.324    47.010     1.000     <#0>     0     0.000     0
```

I want python to recognize the string "PROFILE", and then grab the first column in next line, like "0.000" and "4.324", etc.

As answered by MartijnPieters, it works well. for another question,

as I complemented above, if I want to grab the first columns, than save them to arrays, and then at the end, put all the arrays together into file_2. How should I do? Because I think by writing in every loop, that would be slow. It's better to store all the data, and than put them into file.

Comment: i mean the first column, excuse me, i'll clear it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When looping over a file object, you can use a nested `for` loop to continue reading from the current position; use it to start reading the `PROFILE` section:

```
with open(file_1) as infile, open(file_2, 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith('PROFILE'):
            # found the start of a PROFILE, continue reading with a nested loop
            for line in infile:
                if not line.startswith(' '):
                    # line no longer starts with a space, found the end 
                    # of the section
                    break
                number = line.split()[0]
                outfile.write(number + '\n')
```

The inner loop breaks out when it finds a line that no longer starts with a space; depending on your exact format you may want to tweak that. It'll write *more* lines if there is more than one `PROFILE` section.

Comment: True! I hate when people do that. Btw, I find all your answers helpful and I wasn't the one who downvoted.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py: I could easily have made a mistake; I've thoroughly deserved downvotes on posts before. But I'd love to hear *why* people downvote me, because I am not seeing the mistake here, so far.

Comment: @tobias_k: *you can use a nested for loop to continue reading from the current position*

Comment: @MartijnPieters Really thank you for your helpful answer, I do have another question, with 'write' in every loop, would it slow down the speed？ how to store all data in an array, than together put them into outfile?

Comment: @rankthefirst: file writes are buffered, so no, writing in each loop won't slow things down compared to using your own buffer. The real bottleneck is committing the data to disk anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The task is quite simple to implement:

First, you just open your file and loop through each line:

```
with open("file_1") as file:
    for line in file:
        #todo
```

Then you use an indicator whether you found the string "PROFILE":

```
foundProfile = False
with open("file_1") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.lstrip().starswith("PROFILE"): #something like this
            foundProfile = True
```

Finally you just parse the upcoming lines for your needs:

```
import re #for regex
foundProfile = False
with open("file_1") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.lstrip().starswith("PROFILE"): #something like this
            foundProfile = True
            continue
        if foundProfile:
            m = re.search("^\\s+(\\d+\.\\d+)") #for example
            numer = float(m.group(0))
```

In the end you will just write the parsed data to your new file.

I hope this leads you to your solution.